# minimization of a convex piecewise linear function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{a_1}x + {b_1} & if\,0 \le {x_1} \le x \le {x_2}\\
{a_2}x + {b_2} & if\,{x_2} < x \le {x_3}\\
 \vdots \\
{a_n}x + {b_n} & if\,{x_{n - 1}} < x \le {x_n}
\end{array} \right.$$
be a piecewise continuous function and $0\leq a_1\leq a_2\leq \cdots \leq a_n$.

Formulate the problem of miniimizing $f(x)$ in terms of
linear programming

Comment: Is this problem a homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x)=\max_{i} a_{i}x+b_{i}$.  You can then reformulate the problem as

$\min_{t,x} t $

subject to

$ t \geq a_{i}x + b_{i}$,  $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Comment: but optimal point may not lying in the intervals. can you give an example (for n=2)

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense as a sentence in English, so I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you're concerned that the minimum of the LP might be outside of the interval $[x_{1},x_{n}]$, you can simply add the constraints $x \geq x_{1}$ and $x \leq x_{n}$.  Pick any numbers that you want for $a_{1}$, $b_{1}$, $a_{2}$, and $b_{2}$ and try it.

Comment: Maybe a feasible point do not satisfy all restrictions!
Please give an simple example.